# What's a good RegExp that will strip out all characters except Integers from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to using regexp, can someone give me the regexp that will strip out everything but an integer from a string in javascript?

I would like to take the string "http://www.foo.com/something/1234/somethingelse" and get it down to 1234 as an integer.

Thanks

Comment: Number or integer? Two different things... If you're allowed floats then you're asking a different question.

Comment: what should it do for "ab12xx34"?

Comment: Does that include `hexadecimal`, `octal`, `binary`, `float`, `integer`? We need accurate description please! thanks.

Comment: Sorry - editted to provide more detail.

Comment: decimal values or numeric-stringed values such as IP addresses, how do you plan to address that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var str = "something 123 foo 432";

// Replace all non-digits:
str = str.replace(/\D/g, '');

alert(str); // alerts "123432"
```

---

In response to your edited question, extracting a string of digits from a string can be simple, depending on whether you want to target a specific area of the string or if you simply want to extract the first-occurring string of digits. Try this:

```
var url = "http://www.foo.com/something/1234/somethingelse";
var digitMatch = url.match(/\d+/); // matches one or more digits
alert(digitMatch[0]); // alerts "1234"

// or:
var url = "http://x/y/1234/z/456/v/890";
var digitMatch = url.match(/\d+/g); // matches one or more digits [global search]
digitMatch; // => ['1234', '456', '890']
```

Comment: I'm surprised none of the other answers have used the digit shorthand.

Comment: @Damien: Is there some reason why we should have? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just for integers:

```
[0-9]+
```

The `+` means match 1 or more, and the [0-9] means match any character from the range `0` to `9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
uri = "http://www.foo.com/something/1234/somethingelse";
alert(uri.replace(/.+?\/(\d+)\/.+/, "$1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a character-class that requires the values to be numbers.

```
/[^0-9]/g // matches anything that is NOT 0-9 (only numbers will remain)
```

Comment: Isn't that a negated character class?

Comment: Oh, you're replacing the numbers with nothing, I didn't get that before the comment.

Comment: @Skilldrick - No, I'm replacing the *non-numbers* with nothing :)